# Use std::ifstream::read to count the number of character

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, ifstream

Apparently this piece of code:

```
std::ifstream filev(path, std::ios::binary|std::ios::in);
unsigned long int nData = 0;
filev.read((char*)&nData, sizeof(nData) );
```

As @IgorTandetnik suggested is used to count the number of bytes present in a binary file thanks to the file header, in particular on Windows at the end of execution `nData` will contains the size of the file.

Now i'm wondering why this code on the same processor gives different result on different S.O.

Can someone give me an explanation why MSVC makes this code work?

Comment: `can be used ... to count the number of bytes` No, not really. All it does is read the first 4 or 8 bytes from the file, and interpret them as a representation of an integer. It's possible that the particular file format you are working with happens to store file size in the first few bytes (or a particular file happens to have the first bytes match its file size by pure coincidence), but that's not generally true of an arbitrary file.

Comment: `unsigned long int` is [32 bit large on Windows and 64 bit on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models); that's why the same code retrieves different values from the same file on different platforms (in other words, your code is not portable). I don't see how you can end up with a value of `0x3e4fc7a8` either way though, given the data you show; I suspect you are mistaken in this regard. Anyway, use [`uint32_t` et al](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) when you need integers of a particular bit size in a portable fashion.

Comment: thanks for your help, you are right, i have edited the question according your suggestion, if you make an answer from your comments i will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with file size (it's possible that your file happens to store its own size in its first 4 bytes, but it's not true of an arbitrary file, and in any case is beside the point).

Your code exhibits implementation-defined behavior; in other words, it's non-portable. In particular, `unsigned long int` is [32 bit large on Windows and 64 bit on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), so you read first 4 bytes of a file sometimes, and first 8 bytes other times; naturally, this results in different values when those bytes are interpreted as a binary representation of an integer.

Use [`unit32_t` et al](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) when you need integers of a particular bit size.

This still leaves the fact that binary representation of an integer is itself implementation-defined, even if two implementations use integers of the same size. For example, you are in for a surprise if you ever run this code on a big-endian platform (luckily, those are somewhat rare these days), or one that doesn't use two's-complement representation (those are virtually non-existent).